# Hamiltonian $Z_n$ symmetry

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, quantum-mechanics, symmetry

We consider the following two-dimensional Hamiltonian

$H=\frac{1}{2m}(p_x^2 + p_y^2) +\lambda(x^4+y^4)$

Find the highest $n$ such that the Hamiltonian has a $Z_n$ symmetry.

**My Attempt**

The group $Z_n$ consists of the elements $\{0, 1, 2, ..., n-1\}$ with addition $\mod n$ as the operation.

In order for the Hamiltonian $H$ to have a $Z_n$ symmetry

$\rho(a)^{-1}H\rho(a)=H$

should be satisfied. Such that $\rho(a)$ is the translation in space due to
$a\in Z_n$ and $\rho(a)^{-1}$ is its inverse. Such that

$\rho(a)|\psi\rangle = \{\psi(x-a)\}$

It is easy to see that

$\rho(a)^{-1}p_x\rho(a)=p_x$ (same for $y$ direction)

However

$\rho(a)^{-1}x^4\rho(a)|\psi\rangle = \rho(a)^{-1}\{x^4\psi(x-a)\} = (x + a)^4|\psi\rangle $

Therefore, in order for the Hamiltonian to have a $Z_n$ symmetry, $a$ should be zero meaning that $n$ should be $1$.

I must confess that my knowledge of group theory and symmetry is still very much limited, I therefore apologize if I made any stupid mistakes in my attempt.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: $\rho(a)$ need not be a space translation. For example with $n = 2$ the Hamiltonian has a reflection symmetry $(x, y) \mapsto (-x, -y)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Is there a way to find all the possible symmetries?

Comment: Actually I have no idea. It seems potentially difficult to rule out exotic symmetries given by strange maps $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. I don't know what the person who wrote this problem had in mind.

Comment: It is harder to prove than I thought it would be, then.
As for the reflection symmetry, I suppose you mean $\rho(a)|\psi\rangle = \{\psi(-x)\}$ may I ask why it is so for $n=2$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is so"? Reflection is a map of order $2$: if you reflect twice you get the same wavefunction back.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear.
Shouldn't we get the same wave function back for any even $n$? Since if you reflect four times or six times you would get the same wavefunction again.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, and we do. What is your question...?

Comment: I am searching for the highest $n$ such that the Hamiltonian has a $Z_n$ symmetry. Would that mean that the highest $n$ is infinity? Since the Hamiltonian has a symmetry for all even $n$.

Comment: No, that's not what it means to have a $\mathbb{Z}_n$ symmetry. A $\mathbb{Z}_n$ symmetry means you have a map $g$ such that $g$ applied $n$ times is the identity map, but $g$ applied any fewer than $n$ times is not. For example $(x, y) \mapsto (ix, iy)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_4$ symmetry (it's not a symmetry of this Hamiltonian though). Reflection is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. We only studied translation symmetry in class so I was quite confused.

Thank you very much for your time. Have a good day!